# Frame count mismatch after generating resized proxy file with movflags option

Tags: ffmpeg, frame

I am using FFMpeg to generate a down-sized proxy video for downstream processing.
I am piping the video into FFMpeg as a stream and piping the resulting proxy video directly back to the calling application as a stream.
In order to do this I use the '-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov' option in order to place the 'moov' atoms to the start of the stream.
This all works fine, however the downstream process that uses the proxy video is throwing an error because the frame count in the proxy video does not match the frame count defined in the file's metadata.
In order to verify this, I ran the following FFMpeg command to export the individual frames of the proxy video to a sub-directory.

ffmpeg -i proxy_video.mp4 frames/$filename%03d.bmp

I then count the number of frames generated as follows.
ls frames | wc -l

For my small sample video this gives me a count of 167.

I then used FFProbe to get the number of frames for the video as follows.
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames proxy_video.mp4

For the same video I get a count of 165.
Looking at the original video there are indeed 165 frames, and looking at the bmp files generated for the proxy, it appears that two extra frames are added at the start.
The two extra frames are not a problem, but the count of actual frames vs frames defined in metadata must match.

Is there a way I can update the frame count in the header, or possibly a way to prevent the generation of the extra frames?

The FFMpeg command I am running is as follows.
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -vf scale=480:-2 -f mov -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov proxy_video.mp4

I am running this on Mac OS 12.6.1 and have also observed the problem on Ubuntu 20.04

The output from my FFMpeg  version is as follows,

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
```

Thank you for your help
Mike

Addendum.  Full output from FFMpeg is below.

```
 % ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -vf scale=480:-2 -f mov -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov proxy_video.mp4
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-05-17T20:57:37.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:05.51, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10528 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10189 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-17T20:57:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-17T20:57:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] profile High, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to 'proxy_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 480x270 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-17T20:57:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (.mp3 / 0x33706D2E), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-17T20:57:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libmp3lame
frame=  165 fps= 52 q=-1.0 Lsize=     551kB time=00:00:05.52 bitrate= 817.8kbits/s speed=1.74x    
video:461kB audio:87kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.689201%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] frame I:1     Avg QP:24.34  size: 27213
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] frame P:46    Avg QP:25.37  size:  7748
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] frame B:118   Avg QP:30.86  size:   741
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] consecutive B-frames:  4.2%  0.0%  3.6% 92.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] mb I  I16..4:  0.8% 38.2% 61.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  1.5%  1.0%  P16..4: 38.2% 28.3% 24.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 6.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 42.5%  7.1%  2.2%  direct: 1.7%  skip:46.4%  L0:36.8% L1:48.0% BI:15.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] 8x8 transform intra:45.4% inter:44.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 75.9% 95.1% 82.9% inter: 17.6% 15.2% 5.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] i16 v,h,dc,p: 44% 25% 23%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 13% 22%  5%  6%  7%  6%  8% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 14% 15%  8%  9%  9%  8%  9%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] i8c dc,h,v,p: 49% 18% 23% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] Weighted P-Frames: Y:17.4% UV:17.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] ref P L0: 67.5% 15.9%  8.5%  7.7%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] ref B L0: 88.5%  9.1%  2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] ref B L1: 91.4%  8.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fd91e206000] kb/s:685.25
```

Comment: Share the full readout of `ffmpeg -i input`

Comment: Thanks, I have added the full output from the ffmpeg -i input command.

Comment: It shows expected no. of frames output - 165.

Comment: Yes it does report 165 frames, however if I output the individual frames as bmp files to a directory called 'frames' as follows, it results in 167 bmp files, two of which are copies of the first frame.

`ffmpeg -i proxy_video.mp4 frames/$filename%03d.bmp`

Comment: If you are counting frames using `ls frames | wc -l` then that's wrong as the two directory placeholders are also counted in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have accounted for the directory placeholder.  On the Mac it is only one extra count BTW.  When I generate the bmp files for the original file, and then generate the bmp files for the proxy file, there are two extra frames in the proxy folder as compared to that for the original file.